# For file upload which is better Google gears HTML 5?

Tags: asp.net, html, google-gears

which one is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you meant `file storage`.
HTML5 is good on the browsers that support it. Otherwise go with Google Gears or better with Both.

Comment: +1 for both. Do a check to see if `file storage` is available, this will be the better of the two. If not, fall back on Gears.